# Она сказала: "да"

Tags: орфография, прямая-речь

Верна ли пунктуация в выражении?

Контекст: в ответ на приглашение замуж.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Возможные варианты оформления:** Она сказала: да. Она сказала "да". Она сказала: "Да".

ДА, частица. 1. Выражает согласие при ответе (противоп.: нет). Вы здесь? - Да.

Короткий ответ **оформляется различным образом:**

1) **Классическая прямая речь**: Анна Андреевна выслушала все это и сказала: «**Да, да**».И он сказал: «Хочешь, я покажу тебе фиолетовую поляну?» А я сказала: «**Да**».

2) **БСП:** Женщина обещала подумать… подумала и сказала: **да**.

В том числе (в авторском варианте) используется тире, а не двоеточие: Ты сказала ― **нет**, Я услышал ― **да**… Затерялся след у того пруда. Ты сказала ― **да**, Я услышал ― **нет**.

3) **Дополнение** (в кавычках): Через неделю, когда он позвонил вновь, я сказала «**да**». Но она сказала «**да**» не задумываясь.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Не вижу во втором случае БСП, это тоже прямая речь, только с пропуском кавычек, и в этом случае тоже авторское оформление, потому что кавычками не выделяется прямая речь, если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, если совпадает  с косвенной речью. Может, здесь этот случай, но разговорный.

Comment: У Розенталя в теме БСП: Я тебе определённо скажу: у тебя есть талант (Ф.);  Я говорю: не сдамся (Л. Т.).

Comment: Уважаемая Sibylla, надеюсь, Вы понимаете, что Розенталь привёл примеры реплик в виде БСП, а в Вашем примере слова автора Женщина обещала подумать… подумала и сказала, а потом то, что женщина сказала. Это прямая речь, и она должна быть оформлена как прямая речь или как дополнение, а всё остальное - в обход правил, так что этот вариант неверен.

Comment: Можно найти много примеров в литературе, когда для передачи дословного высказывания в самых разных ситуациях применялась форма БСП, а именно: двоеточие, строчная буква, отсутствие кавычек.  Примеры: Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться? Я говорил тебе: страшися девы милой!Я хотела его забрать, но она сказала ― не надо. [Андрей Геласимов. Жанна (2001)]― Не знаю. Она сказала: ничего. ― В каком смысле ― ничего?

Comment: Мне кажется, что есть понятие о дословном высказывании, о точной передачи чужой речи и есть различные способы оформления предложений с таким дословным высказыванием: в виде БСП, в виде классического или упрощенного  варианта передачи прямой речи, с использованием водных слов и т.д. Прямая речь - это чужая речь (содержание),  а БСП - это  вид сложного предложения (форма), как их можно сравнивть, это вещи разного порядка.

Comment: Я говорю не вообще, а о данном высказывании. Вас спросили, правильно ли оформлено высказывание, и вы предложили 2 реальных варианта, а  один весьма сомнительный. Предлагается предложение с прямой речью, вот и оформлять надо как прямую речь или как предложение, в котором "да" - отдельно сказанное слово, дополнение.

Comment: Здесь еще  от контекста и от наличия паузы выбор зависит. Нет паузы - значит, это дополнение (Что он тебе сказала? - Она сказала "да"). Это пересказ разговора. А в реальном времени пауза есть, и надо бы классический вариант использовать, но для прямой речи из одного слова и  БСП подойдет. Главное - эта форма встречается в литературе для передачи дословных высказываний, так почему ее считать сомнительной?

Comment: Я как раз о "для прямой речи из одного слова и БСП подойдет" . Прямая речь из одного слова - нормально, а  предложение из  одного слова, являющегося частицей, - сомнительно, что-то авторское, а Вы представили как норму.